# Does ExtJS support decoding of OOXML or ODF files?

Tags: javascript, extjs, openxml, odf

I want to develop a web office project just like Google Docs and ExtJS seems good. Can ExtJS read OOXML or ODF natively? Or is there any open source project which can help ExtJS decode OOXML or ODF files and edit them?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to read the file with a server side script using something like PHP. Then pass this to the client side using AJAX.

ExtJS has the AjaxRequest method which you can use to get data from the server. Then pass the response text to the value property of the element you're using to display the file.

Going to be working on something similar myself soon.

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS is a client side javascript framework. It cannot read any files be it OOXML,ODF or PDF. Are you trying to display a file or download it? there is no file handling involved with ExtJS.

Comment: Many thanks, I am trying to display a OOXML file as word. Not just develop a download UI

Comment: I have a OOXML file on server,  I just want to display it to user, and user can do some simple edit operation

Answer (score 1):

try to look at odf javascript framework: http://webodf.org/demo/

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is preview the google doc in your client side application, grab the preview url of the doc (every doc should have one) then display that document in an iframe in your extjs application.